# Swift reset class dataModel

Tags: swift, class, struct, model

I have a registration flow in same class data model instead of struct data, passing through two pages. It can modify the same data model before submitting registration form.

However, the class data model is cached when reopen the registration flow again. I would like to clear / reset all data.

But, it requires all the values to be optional, no singleton. How can i achieve the reset data? Please help..

```
class RegistrationDataModel {
   var username: String?
   var password: String?
   var email: String?
   var mobile: String?
}
```

```
struct registrationViewModel {
   init(
        registrationDataModel: RegistrationDataModel = .init()
    )  {
        self.registrationDataModel = registrationDataModel
     }
}
```

```
class FormOne: UIViewController {
       func routeToFormTwo() {
           FormTwo(formData: viewModel.registrationDataModel)               
       }
}
```

```
class FormTwo: UIViewController {
   init(
        formData: RegistrationDataModel = .init(),
    )  {
        self.formData = formData
     }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with Registration Form code. When and how are you initialising the `RegistrationDataModel`?

Comment: Code updated.  The form one & two communicate each other with same data model successfully.  But I don’t know how to clear the class data model when i go to registration flow again

Comment: Call a reset method in viewDidLoad in FormOne that clears the properties

Comment: how to reset the RegistrationDataModel

Comment: Isn't that obvious? You write a method that resets all properties and then call it from the view controller as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: You never save the second view controller. Your is either incomplete or invalid. Resetting an optional is setting its value to nil. If your model is unique for the application you should create a static var that hold it and that can be accessed by all view controller.